# After pivoting a df using gather and spread can I order the rows based on new Var variable?

Tags: r, dplyr

Sample data:

```
sample_data <- data.frame(
  Device = c("Desktop", "Desktop", "Desktop", "Tablet", "Tablet", "Tablet", "Mobile", "Mobile", "Mobile"),
  Date_Range = seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2017-01-30"), by = 1),
  Sessions = ceiling(rnorm(90, mean = 3000, sd = 300)),
  Conversion1 = ceiling(rnorm(90, mean = 800, sd = 100)),
  Conversion2 = ceiling(rnorm(90, mean = 400, sd = 50))
)
```

Some wrangling with dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
example <- tbl_df(sample_data) %>%
  group_by(Date_Range) %>%
  summarize(Sessions = sum(Sessions),
            Con1 = sum(Conversion1),
            Con2 = sum(Conversion2)) %>%
  mutate(Registration_Rate = round(Con1/Sessions,2),
         Conversion_Rate = round(Con2/Sessions,2)) %>%
  gather(Var, Val, - Date_Range) %>%
  group_by(Date_Range) %>%
  spread(Date_Range, Val)
```

This results in a left to right reading trend, by date, of KPIs including sessions, conversions and resulting conversion rates.

Screen:
[image]

I would like to order these rows. Currently the order of rows reads:

Con1, Con2, Conversion_Rate, Registration_Rate, Sessions (Looks like it's in alphabetical order).

Specifically I would like the table in the following order:
Sessions, Con1, Con2, Registration_Rate, Conversion_Rate.

I looked at row.names(example) but that returns a character vector of 1:5 (yes character).

Ideally I would be able to sort the rows by the Var variable created during the gather() operation. So sort them on name rather than index. But not at the sacrifice of simplicity.

Is there a straight forwards way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be:

```
example <- tbl_df(sample_data) %>%
  group_by(Date_Range) %>%
  summarize(Sessions = sum(Sessions),
            Con1 = sum(Conversion1),
            Con2 = sum(Conversion2)) %>%
  mutate(Registration_Rate = round(Con1/Sessions,2),
         Conversion_Rate = round(Con2/Sessions,2)) %>%
  gather(Var, Val, - Date_Range) %>%
  group_by(Date_Range) %>%
  spread(Date_Range, Val)%>%
  mutate(Var =  factor(Var, levels = c("Sessions", "Con1", "Con2", "Registration_Rate", "Conversion_Rate"))) %>%
  arrange(Var)
```

`Var` is a character vector, so turning it into a factor and setting the `levels` to the desired order means that `arrange()` will sort according to these levels.

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much.